# Defining implicit imports causes an error with other imports

Tags: vb.net

I have an application built in VB.NET. Everything is working great, here are the imports I'm using....

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data.Odbc
Imports System.Windows.Forms.Control
Imports System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal
Imports System.IO
```

I'm trying to do something with excel and added the following import which causes me some issues.....

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
```

In Public Class I have this...

```
Private DtTable as DataTable
```

The errors are:

> DataTable is ambiguous, imported from the namespaces or types
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, System.Data'.

also, I have a function where I use this as a paramter...

```
ByRef c As Windows.Forms.ComboBox
```

I get the following error...

> Type Windows.Forms.Combobox is not defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to declare explicity your `DataTable` like this:

```
Private DtTable as Data.DataTable
```

The same for the second error. Declare it like this:

```
ByRef c As System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
```

Comment: Or for the latter just Import System.Windows.Forms  and use Dim C as Combobox

Comment: works great - i marked @Trevor since both of your answers work but he answered first! gotta be fair

Comment: @BobSki in fact, i answered first, but he deserves it i don't care about rep, don't worry :) Glad it works

Answer (score 2):

That is because the name DataTable is in multiple namespaces. Do it this way instead.

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
Private xlTable as Excel.DataTable
```

or, if you want the standard DataTable

```
Private dtTable as DataTable
```

And you missed the "System" part in the combox scope. But again, you are better doing it this way.

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms
ByRef c As ComboBox
```